# How to calculate time difference in Excel based on values from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For the table below, I would like to write a formula that calculates the difference in timestamps (converted to minutes) between events 'ER Sepsis Triage' & 'IV Antibiotics' for every case_id

[image: Table I'm working on]

New to excel and havent written a lot of formulas and macros, sorry! How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could perform something like this in Column D; however, most rows would simply be "NA". In this example, I've added the distinct CaseIDs to column E and then running formulas against original data in columns A through C.

**Cell F2 formula**, which is showing the first Sepsis Triage event for that case. If no event, then return "na".

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,F$1)>0,MINIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,F$1),"na")
```

**Cell G2 formula**, which is showing the first IV Antibiotics event for that case. If no event, then return "na".

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,G$1)>0,MINIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,G$1),"na")
```

**Cell H2 formula**, which is calculating the time (in minutes) between the two events. If error, return "na".

```
=IFERROR((G2-F2)*1440,"na")
```

Drag down your formulas and you're done.

[image]